# Prevent people from accessing your classes and include files directly

Tags: php, security

I'm making my own MVC framework and I remember seeing something like this in phpBB forums index page code:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
```

and then in the files that are only ment to be included and not directly accessed it has this at the top:

```
if(!defined('IN_PHPBB')) {
    die();
}
```

I was wondering if that is neccessary especially with class files because if they are directly accessed they won't run anyway since they were not instantiated.

Comment: i dont thinks this may cause any problem , but i prefer add these simple lines in all my files , and restrict users accessing any useless file directly.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it would not cause any problems so I think I will do it.

Comment: If your classes cannot be included manually, your framework is broken by design.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to put a file .htaccess with with the directive **deny from all** inside the folder with your php class files.
The official documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `.htaccess` for _preventing_ access. By default, the whole web application should work in `deny from all` mode, and only certain (/public) directory and its contents should be made accessible (with `.htaccess`, or, even better, with Apache conf file - blocking the overrides to increase the performance).